# Why do most introductory texts on QM use the Schrödinger formulation rather than Heisenberg's matrix mechanics?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, education, linear-algebra

I know they're mathematically equivalent, and that makes intuitive sense, seeing as linear differential equations can in general be solved using matrices and other linear algebra approaches. In fact, when I took diff eq several years ago, we had a whole section on the relationship between linear algebra and linear DE's, and it made solving the linear DE's much simpler.

But of course, the Schrödinger equation is much harder to solve than the toy problems worked on in an introductory DE class, so if we already have a fully worked out version of matrix mechanics, why don't we *always* just use that, rather than trying to solve the Schrödinger equation directly?  And why do so many introductory texts skip over the matrix mechanics entirely, or wait a while to bring it up, focusing so heavily on the Schrödinger equation instead?  Solving DE's is generally harder than working with linear algebra, so why would most texts *start* with the harder version?  Or, alternatively, why don't they just introduce both of them together?

I've seen some other posts on the subject and some people said it's because seeing particles as waves is more insightful and the matrix mechanics don't give us this picture.  But if they're ultimately mathematically equivalent, the matrix mechanics formulation surely has a version of wavefunctions?  In which case, shouldn't we get the same insight?

Comment: There are plenty of texts (Townsend and McIntyre are two that come to mind) these days that use a "spins-first" approach; i.e., they first cover finite dimensional quantum systems that are thereby described using matrix algebra.  These tend to be newer books though.  Historically, textbooks have taken a wave-mechanics-first approach partially for historical reasons but also because it seems a common view that students are more *familiar* with diff'l eq'ns than with complex inner product spaces (and their matrix alegbra tends to be pretty rusty in my experience!).

Comment: That said, the two formalism might be "mathematically equivalent" (at least where a classical analogue of the system exists and where it makes some sense to talk about infinite matrices), but they are *conceptually* pretty different, and lead to different ways of thinking about things, and are suitable for different problems.  We really need to learn both and be able to smoothly go back and forth. Pedagogically, however, starting with one and then bringing in the other slowly is easier, I think.

Comment: To my mind, it's not about whether students are unfamiliar to matrices, but rather, starting from waves gives a much more natural transition between CM and QM, whereas the matrix approach starts directly from postulates, and that can be hard to swallow from a newbie's point of view...

Comment: Schrödinger's approach is more concrete and physical. Heisenberg's is more abstract and mathematical. Nothing wrong with abstraction as a tool, but a physicist should ground understanding on the phenomena, not the math.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first non-trivial problem that you solve in a quantum mechanics course is the Hydrogen atom (or, at least, the Coulomb potential -- Hydrogen minus any fine structure). This is usually the pinnacle of the first semester of quantum mechanics, and represents the ability to apply a lot of formalism at a real, physical problem, that connects with the observations that motivated quantum mechanics. I think it is important for students to be able to achieve such a milestone.

You *can* derive the Hydrogen spectrum with other approaches (operator or path integral for example), but it requires noticing and then taking advantage of a hidden $SO(4)$ symmetry of the Hamiltonian -- very elegant but non-direct compared to finding a series solution to Schrodinger's equation as a linear PDE.

I actually think there are many advantages to starting from the Heisenberg picture (or even the path integral), or at least learning about them earlier than is taught in, say, Griffifths' book. For example, my experience, many students have difficulty correctly generalizing the Schrodinger picture from one particle to two particles (there is a temptation to think of *two wavefunctions* rather than *one wavefunction on a larger space*), and I think that generalization is easier in the Heisenberg picture or using path integrals.

To summarize, independent of subjective notions of which formalism is "more intuitive," I think being able to solve the Hydrogen atom (Coulomb potential) with relatively little new-to-the-students mathematics is a major advantage to using the Schrodinger picture in a first quantum mechanics course.

Answer (score 0):

I think the preference of Schrödinger's formulation
(i.e. partial differential equation) over Heisenberg's
formulation (i.e. matrices) is largely an educational thing.

When students (especially high school students) are introduced to quantum mechanics,
they are already familiar with waves
(e.g. sound waves and light waves),
but usually did not yet encounter matrices.

By the way: This was the same situation when Schrödinger
and Heisenberg published their approaches (1926 and 1925).
Quoted from [Matrix mechanics - Matrix basics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_mechanics#Matrix_basics):

> When it was introduced by Werner Heisenberg, Max Born and
> Pascual Jordan in 1925, matrix mechanics was not immediately
> accepted and was a source of controversy, at first. Schrödinger's
> later introduction of wave mechanics was greatly favored.

Comment: "When students are introduced to quantum mechanics, they are already familiar with differential equations (e.g. the wave equation for sound and light), but usually did not yet encounter matrix algebra."  Wait, are you telling me physics students aren't generally required to take at least an introductory linear algebra course as part of the basic mathematical requirements?  I'm an electrical engineering student (with a large interest in physics) and linear algebra is required for my degree.  Plus, even in my diff eq course, we used matrices to solve systems of linear DEs.

Comment: @MikaylaEckelCifrese I am thinking more about physics in high school
(i.e. before university). You can introduce Schrödinger's approach
even without using differential equations. But you can't introduce
Heisenberg's approach without using matrices.